# Is there an alternate syntax to typedef function pointers?

Tags: c, function-pointers, typedef

For doing a typedef for a function pointer, we do something like this,

```
typedef int (*func) (char*);
typedef struct{
  char * name;
  func f1; 
}
```

As opposed to this, I came across a code, which I don't understand.

```
typedef int rl_icpfunc_t (char *);
typedef struct {
   char *name;         /* User printable name of the function. */
   rl_icpfunc_t *func; /* Function to call to do the job. */
   char *doc;          /* Documentation for this function.  */
}COMMAND;
```

This is a code snippet from an example of the libedit library. Can someone please explain this to me?

Comment: It is an int function that takes a char* parameter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
typedef int rl_icpfunc_t (char *);
```

is defining a function prototype as type.

```
rl_icpfunc_t * func;
```

defines `func` to be a pointer to the former.

This is as opposed to defining a function pointer type directly via:

```
typedef int (*prl_icpfunc_t) (char *);
prl_icpfunc_t func;
```

The result of both approches is the same: A pointer `func`, pointing  to a function returning `int` and taking one argument, that is a `char*`.

Comment: Can u explain a bit more ? Are you saying that the second scenario is an error situation ?

Comment: @Ankit: Both approaches to define a function-pointer are valid.

Comment: Not only is this (former) syntax legal - I consider it superior to the more common way of `typedef`ing the function pointer (latter example) - because it retains the characteristics of a pointer in the type declarations afterwards (similar issue: it is considered bad practice to `typedef` pointers to ordinary data types, too...).

Comment: @Aconcagua: How please is "*this (former) syntax*" illegal? Which warnings/errors does your C11 compiler issue?

Comment: @alk "Not only legal, but even superior" Did I express myself badly?

Comment: @Aconcagua: Oh well, I obviously misread your comment. All good. Please excuse! :}

Comment: @Aconcagua: And I do agree with you that the former way is the more explicit way to use `typedef`.

Answer (score 2):

Is it correct to use **typedef int rl_icpfunc_t (char *);** ?

Yes that means `rl_icpfunc_t` is a function that takes a pointer to char and return and int. **You can use `rt_icpfunct_t` in place of a normal type**, thus `rl_icpfunc_t *func` means that `func` is a pointer to function of type `rt_icpfunct_t`

Comment: The difference is that in the second scenario while doing typedef rl_icpfunc_t is used instead of (*rl_icpfunc_t). And then it is used as rl_icpfunc_t * func, rather than rl_icpfunc_t func. This is where my doubt is. Is this allowed ? Or does it mean something diferent ?

Comment: What's not clear to you? The function pointer declared inside the struct `COMMAND` ?

Comment: yes i mean to ask is it correct to use **typedef int rl_icpfunc_t (char *);** ?

Comment: I think so, that means `rl_icpfunc_t` is a function that takes a pointer to char and return and int. You can use `rt_icpfunct_t` in place of a normal type, thus `rl_icpfunc_t *func` means that `func` is a pointer to function of type `rl_icpfunc_t`