# Alternate function syntax/function prototypes?

Tags: c++, syntax, function-pointers, function-prototypes

For all the time I've been using function pointers in C++ I've been declaring them as `void (*function)(void)`. This is how I originally saw it in a tutorial and [how tutorials still teach it](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/function-pointers.html).

But today, I was reading wikipedia's article about higher order functions when I discovered an example using an alternate syntax in which the `*` and the brackets surrounding the function pointer's variable/type name were not present, as seen [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function#Function_pointers).

I tested to see if the form `void function(void)` worked for variables, arguments and typedefs. It didn't work for variables but it worked for arguments and typedefs with no apparent change, practically interchangeable with the standard function pointer syntax.

I dug a bit further and found [an SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32065980/is-there-an-alternate-syntax-to-typedef-function-pointers) that seems to imply it's the syntax for a 'function prototype' rather than a function pointer. However [wikipedia's explanation of function prototypes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_prototype) sounds a lot like just predeclaring functions.

I apologise for the wide scope of my question, but **what exactly is this syntax?**

- Does it define a 'function prototype' or a function pointer?
- If it's a function prototype, are function pointers and function
  prototypes the same or do they just behave the same?
- If it's not a function prototype does that mean 'function prototypes'
  are just predeclarations of functions?
- If this syntax is equivalent to the standard function pointer
  syntax, why is the more verbose (and arguably harder to read) syntax
  the more commonly taught form?
- Do the syntaxes produce different results/have different meanings
  and I somehow haven't noticed?

Comment: On a mobile so not going to write a full answer, but the syntax you show will only work in a typedef. It's all a bit of a mess!

Comment: One place you often see function pointers is as a parameter (`void(*param)()`). That's the one case where writing `void param()` will be equivalent in the same way that `int[N]` as a function parameter is actually `int*`, but different everywhere else.

Comment: @chris I just double checked and it seems I did forget to test the variable case. I was half way through writing when I started doing more research and writing this question, so I forgot I hadn't actually pressed the compile button. I've now fixed that mistake in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they're not the same. Anymore than arrays and pointers are not the same just because you can write `int A[]` as a parameter. The specific rule can be found in the draft standard n4567:

> §8.3.5/5 ... After determining the type of each parameter, any
>   parameter of type "array of `T`" or of function type T is adjusted to
>   be "pointer to `T`". ...

It is more explicit later on:

> §13.2/3 ...
>
> - Parameter declarations that differ only in that one is a function type and the other is a pointer to the same function type are
>     equivalent. That is, the function type is adjusted to become a pointer
>     to function type (8.3.5). [ *Example:*
>
>   ```
>    void h(int());
>    void h(int (*)());     // redeclaration of h(int())
>    void h(int x()) { }    // definition of h(int())
>    void h(int (*x)()) { } // ill-formed: redefinition of h(int())
>   ```
>
>   — *end example* ] ...

The rule applies in other places as well (not a complete list):

- non-type template parameters
- template argument deduction
- exception handlers